# Why is get get_queryset() not returning the right results?

Tags: django, django-views

I have two models, `Recieved_order` and `order`,

```
class Order(SmartModel):

    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,null=True,blank=True,default = None,help_text="The restaurant the customer order from")
    #contact info
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50,help_text="Needed as alternative")
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(max_length=20,default='+25078######')

class Recieved_Order(SmartModel):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,auto_now_add=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9,decimal_places=2)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
```

i want a restaurant manager(user), to be able to receive orders(`Recieved_order`) made to his specific restaurants when logged in, to achieve this, i have the following in views.py

```
class Recieved_OrderCRUDL(SmartCRUDL):
    model = Recieved_Order
    actions = ('create','read','update','delete','list')
    permissions = True

    class List(SmartListView):
        fields = ('order_email','order_mobile','order_billing_city','item.name','item.price','quantity','order_id','order_restaurant')
        search_fields = ('date_added',)

        def get_queryset(self,*args,**kwargs):
            queryset = super(Recieved_OrderCRUDL.List, self).get_queryset(*args,**kwargs)
            if self.request.user.is_superuser:
                return queryset
            return queryset.filter(order=self.request.user)
```

with the above i am testing on two different restaurants, the restaurant and its not working out as it should. its returning the wrong orders for a given restaurant.

What am i not doing right with `get_queryset()`.

Comment: are you sure self.request gives a valid request object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a user (what you refer to as a manager) only able to view their own orders, you need to change things... `Restaurant` will need to have a field that points to a `User` (let's call it `user` and assume it's a `ForeignKey`) Then you can do something like

```
if self.request.user.is_superuser:
    return queryset
return queryset.filter(order__restaurant__user=self.request.user)
```

As pointed out by @Joe Holloway, you should not be trying to filter on the `order` field with a `user` object...

The other odd thing I wanted to point out is

```
fields = ('order_email','order_mobile','order_billing_city','item.name','item.price','quantity','order_id','order_restaurant')
```

You appear to be using a mixture of ways to attempt to access things...
You should be using `__` (that's 2 underscores) to access relations, not `_` or `.`

Answer (score 2):

There's something confusing going on here:

```
return queryset.filter(order=self.request.user)
```

You're telling it to build a query that filters `Order` objects against `User` objects.

Is there something missing in your sample code that ties orders back to users such that a proper join can be constructed?

Comment: i have a get_queryset() function for the `Order` model, that ends like `return queryset.filter(restaurant=self.request.user)`

Comment: you were right, i was missing something and @ngenator pointed it out in his answer...thanks